# Ошибки компиляции при попытке создать триггер на представление

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create table t (
  id number primary key,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

create table t2 (
   id number primary key,
   name2 varchar(100) not null,
   foreign key (id) references t(id)
);

create view v as
select t.id, t.name, t2.name2 from t, t2 where t.id = t2.id;


create or replace trigger trg
instead of insert on v
begin
insert into t values(:new.id, :new.name);
insert into t2 values(:new.id, :new.name2);
end trg;
```

Есть 2 таблицы, которые соединяются в представление по `id`.
Хочу выполнять `insert` в это представление, поэтому сделал триггер.
Но он компилируется с ошибкой.

Посмотрел на [сайте](https://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-plsql-instead-of-trigger-example/), там точно как у меня. Почему ошибка?

Comment: проверил у себя. компилируется без ошибок, вставка работает. Какие ошибки при компиляции у вас ? Что то мне подсказывает, что у вас среда разработки, в которой вы это делаете глючит ...

Comment: Да, это действительно был мой фэйл, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Типичная ошибка при переносе кода из различных внешних источников.

Ошибку можно воспроизвести, например, скопировав пример  из вопроса (несколько упростил) в рабочую область SQL Developer:

```
create or replace view v as select 'key 1' key, 1 val from dual;

View V created.

create or replace trigger trig1 instead of insert on v
begin null;
end trig1;

Trigger TRIG1 compiled

Errors: check compiler log
```

Первая команда выполнилась, а со второй триггер компилируется с ошибкой. Это потому, что первая - это SQL команда и символ `;` завершает её, а вторая содержит PL/SQL блок и символ `;` является частью синтаксиса.

Символ завершения команды с PL/SQL блоком обычно `/`, в примерах кода во внешних источниках он часто опускается (подробнее см. документацию к среде разработки):

```
create or replace trigger trig1 instead of insert on v
begin null;
end trig1;
/

Trigger TRIG1 compiled
```